# Can't change "new item" form from calendar within SP Online connected to MS Teams

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calendar, form, team-sites

I frequently use MS Teams. As with every team created there's also a new site collection in SP online, I implemented a lot in such site collections.

However, one of my frequent tools in such SCs is the good old SharePoint calendar. It can be customized in the way as it was on SP 2010.

I wanted to change the behavior of the "new item" form, i.e. add some formatted text or information, but when I navigate to the settings of the calendar and select the form settings, I get the error message, that InfoPath doesn't support modifying the form for this list.

Do I have other means to customize the forms for new items in that list? If I try to open it with SharePoint designer, I apparently lack some rights to get all information. I only see some JSON gibberish when I open NewForm.aspx

On the other hand, PowerApps doesn't seem to work with "old" SharePoint calendar. Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This the expected behavior since **InfoPath doesn't supported customize forms in Event List or Library**.

As you said, PowerApps is only available for modern experience lists, not classic lists.

Currently, we could customize the new and edit form of calendar in SharePoint designer.

Refer to following article:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23955.sharepoint-2013-building-custom-forms.aspx

Comment: Good article. Unfortunately the SC behind teams seems to be restricted somehow, so I can't even load all elements in SP designer. SP designer complains a lot about missing access rights and won't display the navigation bar on the left.

Comment: Please make sure you are a member of one of the following groups at the site collection level to be able to use SharePoint Designer and modify SharePoint content:Site Collection Administrators\Designers\Owners

Comment: I'm member of site owners and I can't find any other group. Is there a trick to display other rights and levels which might be hidden?

Comment: Please go to the root site collection, Site permissions> Advanced permissions settings> Site collection administrators to check whether you have right permissions.

Comment: Checked that. I'm listed as site collection administrator.

Comment: I also found sth strange when checking my permissons on SC level. I'm notified that the following factors affect the level of access for me: 
"Deny" | 
"Add and Customize Pages" | 
"Add, change, or delete HTML pages or Web Part Pages, and edit the Web site using a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible editor."  — Where does that come from?

Comment: Enable custom scripting in admin cenrter and wait for 24 hours: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/allow-or-prevent-custom-script#to-allow-custom-script-on-other-sharepoint-sites

Comment: I guess, the admins won't activate the custom scripting for me. But I'll give it a try!

Comment: If you have any update, please feel free to reply or mark the helpful reply as answer, thank you for your understanding.